# Error importing Role Assignment for Terraform at a storage account scope

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a problem importing a "Role Assignment" for Terraform from a logic app to access a storage table.

```bash
 terraform import -var-file="config/int.tfvars" azurerm_role_assignment.workflow_roles "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/<role-assignment-id>"
```

The resource definition:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "workflow_roles" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage.id
  role_definition_id   = data.azurerm_role_definition.builtin_table_contrib.id <-- definido abajo
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_logic_app_workflow.workflowA.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

The role definition is built-in:

```
data "azurerm_role_definition" "builtin_table_contrib" {
  name = "Storage Table Data Contributor"
}
```

I got this error:

```bash
╷
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "azurerm_role_assignment.workflow_receiver_roles", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only pre-existing
│ objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object
│ for this resource.
╵
```

The  was copied browsing to the storage account, listing and exporting the role assignments from "Access Control" to a  JSON. Like this:

```json
    {
        "RoleAssignmentId": "<role-assignment-id>",   From here taken the id
        "Scope": "/subscriptions/.../storageAccount....",
        "DisplayName": ...,
        "SignInName": ...,
        "RoleDefinitionName": "Storage Table Data Contributor",
        "RoleDefinitionId": ...
        ...
    }
```

I don't know what other ID it could be, if anyone has an idea I would appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

Try with role_definition_name  instead of Id

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "xxx"
    storage_account_name = "remotestatekavstr231"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "builtin_table_contrib" {
  name = "Storage Table Data Contributor"
}

output "role" {
  value = data.azurerm_role_definition.builtin_table_contrib.role_definition_id
}



resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "workflow_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
  role_definition_id   = data.azurerm_role_definition.builtin_table_contrib.role_definition_id
  principal_id         =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

For me it worked with below code  too:

```
data "azurerm_role_definition" "builtin_table_contrib" {
  name = "Storage Table Data Contributor"
}

output "role" {
  value = data.azurerm_role_definition.builtin_table_contrib.role_definition_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "workflow_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
  role_definition_id   = data.azurerm_role_definition.builtin_table_contrib.id
  principal_id         =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
```

Terraform import gives its already managed if roleis assignd successfully

```
terraform import azurerm_role_assignment.workflow_receiver_roles /subscriptions/8ae084xxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mynewstaccka/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxx
```

[image]

[image]